# CSS font-family is not applied to h1

Tags: html, css, web-frontend, font-family

I added font-family by CSS, it applied to the body but h1 does not change. The below code block shows the CSS and sample HTML:

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
}

.h1{
  color: red;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <body>
    <div class="top-container">
    <img class="top-cloud"  src="img/cute-cloud.png" alt="happy-cloud">
    <div class="text1">
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <h2>I am a <span class="pro">pro</span>grammer </h2>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Could you check what wrong is with my code.

Comment: Remove the dot before ```h1``` in your css.

Comment: remove Dot h1{
  color: red;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
.h1{
}
```

means you have generated the css class with name "h1" which will be applied to html element just as the css classes are applied, i.e

```
<h1 class="h1"></h1>
```

and that will only be applied to those h1 tags which you have applied class attribute for, if you want to apply the css to every h1 element in the files where you have used this css style, then the element name will be mentioned in css without `.` or `#` as follows:

```
h1{
}
```

it's all about your choice.

Answer (score 0):

`.h1` targets the **class** `h1`, to target all the `<h1>`'s, remove the dot:

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
}

h1{
  color: red;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <body>
    <div class="top-container">
    <img class="top-cloud"  src="img/cute-cloud.png" alt="happy-cloud">
    <div class="text1">
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <h2>I am a <span class="pro">pro</span>grammer </h2>
    </div>
  </body>
```

---

#### [w3 CSS Selectors overview](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Do **not** answer questions that are caused by typos. Use the comment option instead and flag the question as
`not reproducable or caused by typos`. Such question hold no value to the community and are removed from SO 
for that reason. As such all awarded reputations are reverted aswell. Therefor there is no reason to *hunt*  reputation
while rbeaking SO guidelines.

Comment: How do you know that was a typo, and not a misunderstanding about css selectors?

Comment: even then a comment would have been sufficient and the same flag applies. The question remains to have no value.